# WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: But I can't see the problem?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to insert data into MySQL via Express, the database table is created as such:

```
create table foods (name VARCHAR(100), typval DECIMAL(8, 2), unit VARCHAR(50), calories DECIMAL(5, 2), carbs DECIMAL(5, 2), fat DECIMAL(5,2), protein DECIMAL(5, 2), salt DECIMAL(5, 2), sugar DECIMAL(5, 2));
```

I have a form which collects user data and the function to post looks something like this:

```
   app.post("/addnewfood", function (req,res) {
    console.log(req.body.name, req.body.typval, req.body.unit, req.body.calories, req.body.carbs, req.body.fat, req.body.protein, req.body.salt, req.body.sugar);
    // saving data in database
    let sqlquery = "INSERT INTO foods (name, typval, unit, calories, carbs, fat, protein, salt, sugar) VALUES (?,?)";
    // execute sql query
    let newrecord = [req.body.name, req.body.typval, req.body.unit, req.body.calories, req.body.carbs, req.body.fat, req.body.protein, req.body.salt, req.body.sugar];
    db.query(sqlquery, newrecord, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
    }else
    res.send("New" + " " + req.body.name + " was added to the database.");
    });
   });
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong since I counted there's 9 different fields I need to fill in for the 9 different columns. I've checked the commas and I can't see anything out of place.

When I try to enter data like: "McDonalds Hamburger, 1.0, Burger, 100.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 1.0, 10.00"

The console.log prints it out fine and it should work however, I get:

ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Your `INSERT` query needs a placeholder for every column you insert.  You only have two placeholders -- two `?` items -- here.

```
 VALUES (?,?)
```

You need nine, one for each column.

```
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: askaldlsjd how did I miss that, fabulous thank you! 